# set listbox items text using collection of objects

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

### Question

I need to be able to set a Listbox controls items text to be a property of a generic object.

```
foreach ( GenericObject obj in _genericObjectsCollection )
{
   listbox1.Items.Add( obj );
   listbox1.Items.Text = obj.ItemsText;
}
```

**Generic object class**

```
public class GenericObject
{
   public string ItemsText { get; set; }
   public OtherClass TheOtherGenericClass { get; set; }
}
```

---

### The Problem

Text is rendered as *"myProject.GenericObject"*

Instead of getting the text property it simple renders the object type.

---

### What I require

Text to render as:

*"Text for generic object 1"*

*"Text for generic object 2"*

and so on for each object in the collection.

---

### Final words

I know that when using a proper datasource you can use the display member property of the listbox control but I get exceptions when using it with a collection as the datasource. It informs me that complex classes cannot be used to accomplish this task.

---

### Response to questions

What happens when I use the datasource property?

**Code I use**

```
    foreach ( GenericObject obj in _genericObjectsCollection  )
    {
        listboxProcessedQuotes.DataSource = obj ;
        listboxProcessedQuotes.DisplayMember = obj.ItemsText;
    }
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ( GenericObject obj in _genericObjectsCollection )
{
   listbox1.Items.Add( obj.itemsText );
}
```

If you also need to be able to get the underlying selected object you can store it in the Tag property:

```
foreach ( GenericObject obj in _genericObjectsCollection )
{
   ListBoxItem itm = new ListBoxItem();
   itm.Content = obj.itemsTxt;
   itm.Tag = obj;
   listbox1.Items.Add(itm);
}
```

Then later, when you get the selected listbox item you can do:

```
itm.Tag as GenericObject
```

Comment: Hi Derek, thanks for the suggestion. Whats the ListBoxItem class you reference?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You should be able to just use the ListBoxItem class.  It is a standard wpf class, like the ListBox.  I included the link above.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply. I somehow tagged the question as WPF instead of Winforms and just noticing now, thats why i asked. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious how you tried to do the display member path for your listbox. It really should be possible. Here's a simple example:

```
//xaml
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox" DisplayMemberPath="MyStringProperty"/>

//code behind
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.LoadItems();
    }

    private void LoadItems()
    {
        ListBox.Items.Add(new MyListItem() { MyBoolProperty = true, MyStringProperty = "Hello" });
        ListBox.Items.Add(new MyListItem() { MyBoolProperty = false, MyStringProperty = "World" });
    }
}

//my object class
public class MyListItem : NotificationObject
{
    private string _myString;
    private bool _myBool;

    public MyListItem()
    { }

    public string MyStringProperty
    {
        get { return _myString; }
        set
        {
            _myString = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("MyStringProperty");
        }
    }

    public bool MyBoolProperty
    {
        get { return _myBool; }
        set
        {
            _myBool = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("MyBoolProperty");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how your `GenericObject` should be:

```
public class GenericObject
{
    private string _itemsText;
    public string itemsText
    {
        get { return _itemsText; }
        set { _itemsText = value; }
    }
}
```

Then create a simple list of your custom object and add it to the `ItemsSource` of the `ListBox`:

```
List<GenericObject> l = new List<GenericObject>();
l.Add(new GenericObject() { itemsText = "test1" });
l.Add(new GenericObject() { itemsText = "test2" });

list1.ItemsSource = l;
```

Pay attention to the XAML declaration of the `ItemTemplate`, I'm using binding:

```
<ListBox x:Name="list1">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding itemsText}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

I suggest to read more about data binding, it's very useful.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612%28v=vs.110%29.aspx